# Convert from 4 bit binary number to 2 bit binary number

Tags: circuit-analysis, adder, conversion, logisim

[image]

I am currently using logisim to output a 2 bit binary number, however, the bit adder releases 4 bit binary number instead. Is there any way to fix this? (I am currently using v 2.14.6 .)

Comment: Use a wire splitter. First item under Wiring. Can't miss it.

Comment: What is logisim? More context please.

Comment: Are you unable to find the splitter, as described? It's easy to use and will easily divide up your bus for you. If that's too hard for you, try Neemann's Digital. It's a lot better and easier to use and it is maintained regularly, too. If you are truly and completely screwed up, I'll write an answer. But this really shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @mhaselup Logisim is a digital simulator, still in wider use, and with some forks.

Comment: How would you assign the 16 possible values of the 4 bit line to the 2 bit line?

Comment: @jonk Thank you very much, the splitter works perfectly.

Comment: @anonymouseeeee No problem. Hope the best for you. If you still struggle, I'll help out. But I think you are fine.

Comment: If you have solved your isse, please write an answer, so that others will recognize your question as answered. And you can later return and mark it. -- If you wonder why, please consider to take the [tour] (again).